# Отправка СМС уведомления с сайта

Tags: smpp, php, sms

Всем привет. Появилась потребность реализовать отправку СМС на телефон
администратору сайта после получения заявки. Например, на сайте есть
кнопка "ЗАКАЗАТЬ ЗВОНОК". Человек на неё кликает, заполняет форму и
отправляет данные, а мне эти данные СМС-кой приходят. Можно ли такое реализовать?

Например, есть сайт [landix.ru](http://landix.ru/), конструктор сайтов. Вот там есть 
функция отправки СМС-уведомлений. Думал это на Битрикс24 работает,
но облазил в нём всё и не нашёл ничего подобного.

Comment: Кстати, есть прогресс? Удалось реализовать?

Comment: Да, реализовал на SMS.ру. Уведомление через почту ...@sms.ru отправляется.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Отправить СМС до абонента возможно через СМС-центр оператора. Непосредственно доступом к СМС-центру оператора занимается либо сам оператор, либо посредник-контора. СМС-центр, как правило, общается с "внешним миром", т.е. клиентами, посредством протокола SMPP. Связь до СМС-центра, как правило, устанавливается через VPN-туннель. В случае с SMPP клиент (т.е. Вы) заключает договор с оператором (посредником), устанавливает соединение по VPN, затем пишет свой код, который "умеет" посылать пакеты PDU (в которых "содержится" СМС - подробнее читайте спецификацию протокола SMPP - она свободно доступна в Интернете) протокола SMPP СМС-центру и получать и обрабатывать их.

Как правило, из-за специфичности протокола SMPP, а также из-за небольшой трудности в реализации программы для программиста, не имевшего опыта с протоколом, и из-за нецелесообразности написания и своей индивидуальной отдельной SMPP-аппликации для небольших проектов, используется HTTP-интерфейс, предоставляемый оператором или посредником: в таком случае вы вызываете обычный URL (вызывается либо "через" VPN, либо URL является публичным в значения параметров URL (возможен и SOAP-вариант) указываются данные авторизации, т.е. логин-пароль), параметры с которого обрабатываются сервером, который потом уже через обобщенный канал передает данные через SMPP СМС-центру. Эта схема предназначена для того, чтобы избавить клиента от разработки аппликаций, использующих SMPP напрямую. Вид URL может быть таким:

```
http://operator-vpn-server.ru:8080/http2smpp/send.app?login=xxx&pass=yyy&from=MYFIRM&to=7920XXXXXXX&txt=Hello%20World&my_msg_id=3F000022&resp=true
```

Принцип работы в этом случае сводится к тому, что оператором создается свой универсальный некий SMPP клиент-концентратор, который подсоединен к СМС-центру оператора же на выходе, а с другой стороны принимает HTTP-запросы извне от многочисленных клиентов, т.е. выполняет роль перекодировщика HTTP-траффика в SMPP протокол. Этим самым достигается эффект упрощенной логики - много клиентов, а обработчик один, тем самым избавляя каждого потребителя-клиента от разработки собственных SMPP приложений. Более того, избавляет персонал от нудных консультаций в ответ на претензии каждого клиента на тему "я все сделал правильно, но ваш SMPP не работает" :)

Для доставки сообщений от абонента до клиента (и статусов доставки посланных вами сообщений) используется опять или SMPP или же Вы предоставляете свой URL, который будет вызывать сторона оператора (посредника) для передачи данных вашей аппликации.

В вашем случае (допустим, выбрана URL-схема) - а ведь данные из формы, которую заполнил посетитель, обрабатываются у вас в каком-то скрипте, - Вы просто добавляете туда же вызов того самого URL, указанного выше, в параметры (текст) которого вписываете нужную информацию: хоть сам текст из формы, хоть просто "Внимание, новая форма заполнена!" - Вам решать.

Comment: А сколько стоит заключение договора с оператором? И целесообразно ли это для маленького проекта, где заявок 10 в день приходит?

Comment: Нецелесообразно) посмотрите в сторону посредников, можно спокойно найти посредников с ценой 15-20коп за смс, а если брать пакетами от 10к штук итого дешевле. Вот думаю вас заинтересует http://sms.ru/?panel=price

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, Я, честно говоря, не знаю расценок в РФ, но, как ниша рынка, эта услуга стоит,я думаю, везде почти одинаково (и относительно дешево). Стоимость, как правило, зависит от  количества: больше пакет - ниже цена.

Comment: http://sms.ru/?panel=price внизу
> Сообщения на собственный номер
Бесплатны до 60 СМС в день, далее оплачиваются по стандартным тарифам.
СМС на свой номер бесплатны только если текст укладывается в 1 SMS сообщение (длина описана выше).

Comment: И? Мне это известно. Для чего мне эта информация? Я спрашивал, чем мэйнсмс.ру лучше, чем смс.ру.

Comment: Оба сайта предоставляют одинаковый подход - решение, именуемое HTTP2SMS API, которое весьма и весьма удобно. Разница всего лишь в ценах.

Answer (score 3):

Есть сайт mainsms там стоимость одной смс 15 копеек. Отправлять смс с сайта можно путём отправки письма. Создать шаблон в Битрикс не составит никакого труда. 
Подобная реализация была реализована мной на сайте интернет-магазина за 5 мин. Цель - отправлять смс оператору при новом заказе.

Comment: А в чём преимущество этого сайта по сравнению с sms.ru? Там тоже можно СМС через E-mail отправлять. А на мэйнсмс что-то не нашёл отправку СМС через E-mail.

UPD: нашёл sms2email

Comment: Сервисом СМС не пользовался. В чём разница не знаю. Может в ценах. В МайнСМС точно можно отправлять через почту. Это на практике проверено. Сообщения приходят практически сразу. Выбрал по рекомендациям на разных форумах.

Answer (score 2):

Все варианты сводятся к использованию API какого-либо сервиса. Какого именно - решать вам. Выбирайте по стоимости, надежности, функционалу, удобству API... Я уже много лет пользуюсь smsclub.mobi. 
Есть отличная пошаговая инструкция [как отправлять смс с помощью PHP](http://freelancer.dn.ua/blog/?p=23#more-23) с конкретными примерами одиночной СМС, массовой рассылки, проверки отчетов о доставке и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, что вам нужно - [jbcallme.ru](http://jbcallme.ru)
. Здесь как раз "Заказ обратного звонка" с смс информированием. Там можно установить либо свой текст смс, либо указать какие поля присылать, например только Имя и Телефон. Да и не только обратный звонок модулем реализуется. Можно сделать заказ с сайта в один клик или контактную форму, суть-то одна и та же. Кстати, смс там вроде как бесплатные на свой номер.