# Sms уведомление с сайта

Tags: sms

Здравствуйте, мне интересно как вы создавали смс уведомлений с сайта, например если клиент заказал на сайте товар потом ему отправляется с сайта смс с текстом "Ваш товар №4444 оформлен и отправлен". Гугл дал куча сервисов, кто пробовал такими сервисами работать? Посоветуйте сервис.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я реализовал рассылки с помощью сайта [sms.ru](http://sms.ru).
Там же и АПИ есть,или же можно скачать с гит-а, [готовый php класс](https://github.com/zelenin/sms_ru), для реализаций задуманного. Класс поддерживает массовую рассылку, умеет подставить имя отправителя, и.тд функций.
Функций-методы очень просты, например вот так выглядят команды отправки:

```
$sms->sms_send( '79112223344', 'Текст SMS' );
$sms->sms_send( '79112223344,79115556677,79118889900', 'Текст SMS' );
```

Остался доволен. И потом,в самой интерфейсе,(sms.ru) можно создать свою группу, и им отправлять бесплатные смс-ки ))

Comment: @Vfvtnjd прикольный сервис и цены вроде ниче если оптом то по 7 копеек

Answer (score 1):

на хабре же обсуждали [Как отправлять уведомления с сайта по SMS?](http://habrahabr.ru/post/47794/). довольно объёмные комментарии.

И на этом сайте уже обсуждалось [Отправка СМС уведомления с сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/230646/php-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0). Ищите внимательнее.

Comment: @spirit, и Вам тоже взгляд на ХК, как на интеллектуальную поисковую систему быстрого реагирования не нравится?

IMHO если всех "отфутболивать", то стоящих вопросов вообще не возникнет, а когда у самому что-то понадобиться быстренько узнать, то никто не подскажет (просто все знатоки уже разбегутся).

Comment: я Вас немного не понял. Вы предлагаете ответить ещё раз то же самое? Если бы на мой вопрос сказали "Вот, рядом задавали, держи ссыль", то я бы сказал спасибо и взял информацию оттуда.
А если у кого есть что написать, то напишут.

Comment: Да, @spirit, по сути Вы так и сделали. +1. А я что-то не по делу "побухтел".

Comment: @spirit, я этими ссылками знаком, а что нить новое от вас?

Answer (score 0):

Я использую сервис SMSintel.ru. Сервис имеет достаточно обширное API по отправке сообщений.