# Реализация SMS-лотереи

Tags: sms

Как работает система SMS-лотереи? Работать должно так: я сообщаю короткий номер, на который нужно будет отправить SMS и стоимость сообщения. И, например, каждый сотый отправитель получает некоторую сумму в виде платежа на мобильный счёт.

Сам разрабатывать не буду, т.к. плохо в этом разбираюсь, но кое-что понимаю всё-таки (занимался самообразованием в этой сфере). Просто хотелось узнать, как работает механизм.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Линк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/230646#230671) - здесь про то, как работать с СМС центром оператора (чтобы не повторяться).

Чтобы начислить деньги на счет абонента, оператор также предоставляет доступ (как правило, через VPN) к некоему интерфейсу (т.н. Billing Facade), на который вы и будете посылать сумму (или код сервиса оказываемой услуги, транслирующейся на стороне оператора в начисление средств на номер абонента), номер абонента и прочие необходимые данные.

Логика (если не вдаваться в детали) банально проста:

- Абоненты шлют СМСы на ваш короткий номер (подробности по ссылке наверху).
- СМС центр "доставляет" их до вашей аппликации (подробности опять же по ссылке наверху).
- Ваша аппликация решает, кому из претендентов повезло.
- Ваша система отправляет на Billing Facade соответствующую команду с номером "счастливчика".
- Вы теряете по 100 рублей на каждого 100-го абонента, а в конце месяца оператор перечисляет вам на счет по 10000 за каждые 100 СМС.
- Чемодан денег, пляж, закат, пальмы, коктейль и томная сисястая красотка, изнемогающая в постели - PROFIT!

Ну а что касается того, как и на чем написать такую программу, а также создать архитектуру приложения со всеми статистиками, то это - отдельный разговор, объем которого не уложится и в 10 ответов.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!